# Ideal way to fill Health app with testing data

Tags: ios, testing, healthkit

I realize that I could write to `HealthKit` for all of the data independently, but I was wondering if there was an official way to fill the `Health` app with fake data for debugging purposes. I looked over all the documentation and couldn't find anything, and I just want to make sure before just writing it from the app.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no official method for creating a fake data set.

Comment: For anybody that ends up on this page, what I ended up doing was simply writing a bunch of random data. This works great in the simulator because you can always easily reset the information, but I would strongly discourage anyone from writing fake data on an actual device due to difficulty deleting it after the data has been saved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this project to help you get testing data:
https://github.com/Comocomo/HealthKitImporter/

Its basically implementing the health kit write methods to insert data into your device / simulator health app from an export.xml file (exported from a device containing healthkit data)

Loading the export.xml file to the project and parsing it by calling:

```
func start() {
        dataImporter = HKimporter {
            if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "export", withExtension: "xml") {
                if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: path) {
                    parser.delegate = self.dataImporter
                    parser.parse()
                    self.dataImporter.saveAllSamples()
                }
            } else {
                print ("file not found")
            }
        }
```

Pretty printing the records

```
extension CustomStringConvertible {
    var description : String {
        var description: String = ""
        //if self is AnyObject {
        //    description = "***** \(type(of: self)) - <\(unsafeAddressOf((self as AnyObject)))>***** \n"
        //} else {
        description = "***** \(type(of: self)) *****\n"
        //}
        let selfMirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in selfMirror.children {
            if let propertyName = child.label {
                description += "\(propertyName): \(child.value)\n"
            }
        }
        return description
    }
}
```

HKImporter for reading the XML records and saving the HK samples

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

class HKRecord: CustomStringConvertible {
    var type: String = String()
    var value: Double = 0
    var unit: String?
    var sourceName: String = String()
    var sourceVersion: String = String()
    var startDate: Date = Date()
    var endDate: Date = Date()
    var creationDate: Date = Date()

    //for workouts
    var activityType: HKWorkoutActivityType? = HKWorkoutActivityType(rawValue: 0)
    var totalEnergyBurned: Double = 0
    var totalDistance: Double = 0
    var totalEnergyBurnedUnit: String = String()
    var totalDistanceUnit: String = String()

    var metadata: [String:String]?
}

class HKimporter : NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {

    var healthStore:HKHealthStore?

    var allHKRecords: [HKRecord] = []
    var allHKSampels: [HKSample] = []

    var eName: String = String()
    var currRecord: HKRecord = HKRecord.init()

    var readCounterLabel: UILabel? = nil
    var writeCounterLabel: UILabel? = nil


    convenience init(completion:@escaping ()->Void) {

        self.init()

        self.healthStore = HKHealthStore.init()

        let shareReadObjectTypes:Set<HKSampleType>? = [
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.flightsClimbed)!,
            // Body Measurements
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.height)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyFatPercentage)!,
            // Nutrient
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryProtein)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryFatTotal)!,
            //                        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryFatSaturated)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryCarbohydrates)!,
            //                        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietarySugar)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryEnergyConsumed)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodGlucose)!,
            // Fitness
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned)!,
            HKWorkoutType.workoutType(),
            // Category
            HKQuantityType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis)!,

            //Heart rate
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRateVariabilitySDNN)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.restingHeartRate)!,

            // Measurements
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyFatPercentage)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.height)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.leanBodyMass)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMassIndex)!,
            // Nutrients
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryFatTotal)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryFatPolyunsaturated)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryFatMonounsaturated)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryFatSaturated)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryCholesterol)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietarySodium)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryCarbohydrates)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryFiber)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietarySugar)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryEnergyConsumed)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryProtein)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryVitaminA)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryVitaminB6)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryVitaminB12)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryVitaminC)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryVitaminD)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryVitaminE)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryVitaminK)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryCalcium)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryIron)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryThiamin)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryRiboflavin)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryNiacin)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryFolate)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryBiotin)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryPantothenicAcid)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryPhosphorus)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryIodine)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryMagnesium)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryZinc)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietarySelenium)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryCopper)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryManganese)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryChromium)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryMolybdenum)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryChloride)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryPotassium)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryCaffeine)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.dietaryWater)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.uvExposure)!,
            // Fitness
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceCycling)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.basalEnergyBurned)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.flightsClimbed)!,
            // Results
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyTemperature)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.respiratoryRate)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.basalBodyTemperature)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodGlucose)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.oxygenSaturation)!,
            HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodAlcoholContent)!]

        self.healthStore?.requestAuthorization(toShare: shareReadObjectTypes, read: shareReadObjectTypes, completion: { (res, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                completion()
            }
        })
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        eName = elementName
        if elementName == "Record" {
            currRecord.type = attributeDict["type"]!
            currRecord.sourceName = attributeDict["sourceName"] ??  ""
            currRecord.sourceVersion = attributeDict["sourceVersion"] ??  ""
            currRecord.value = Double(attributeDict["value"] ?? "0") ?? 0
            currRecord.unit = attributeDict["unit"] ?? ""

            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"
            if let date = formatter.date(from: attributeDict["startDate"]!) {
                currRecord.startDate = date
            }
            if let date = formatter.date(from: attributeDict["endDate"]!){
                currRecord.endDate = date
            }

            if currRecord.startDate >  currRecord.endDate {
                currRecord.startDate = currRecord.endDate
            }

            if let date = formatter.date(from: attributeDict["creationDate"]!){
                currRecord.creationDate = date
            }
        } else if elementName == "MetadataEntry" {
            currRecord.metadata = attributeDict
        } else if elementName == "Workout" {
            print(attributeDict)
            currRecord.type = HKObjectType.workoutType().identifier
            currRecord.activityType = activityByName(activityName: attributeDict["workoutActivityType"] ?? "")
            currRecord.sourceName = attributeDict["sourceName"] ??  ""
            currRecord.sourceVersion = attributeDict["sourceVersion"] ??  ""
            currRecord.value = Double(attributeDict["duration"] ?? "0") ?? 0
            currRecord.unit = attributeDict["durationUnit"] ?? ""
            currRecord.totalDistance = Double(attributeDict["totalDistance"] ?? "0") ?? 0
            currRecord.totalDistanceUnit = attributeDict["totalDistanceUnit"] ??  ""
            currRecord.totalEnergyBurned = Double(attributeDict["totalEnergyBurned"] ?? "0") ?? 0
            currRecord.totalEnergyBurnedUnit = attributeDict["totalEnergyBurnedUnit"] ??  ""

            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"
            if let date = formatter.date(from: attributeDict["startDate"]!) {
                currRecord.startDate = date
            }
            if let date = formatter.date(from: attributeDict["endDate"]!){
                currRecord.endDate = date
            }

            if currRecord.startDate >  currRecord.endDate {
                currRecord.startDate = currRecord.endDate
            }

            if let date = formatter.date(from: attributeDict["creationDate"]!){
                currRecord.creationDate = date
            }
        } else if elementName == "Correlation" {
            return
        } else {
            return
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "Record" || elementName == "Workout" {

            allHKRecords.append(currRecord)
            print(currRecord.description)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.readCounterLabel?.text = "\(self.allHKRecords.count)"
            }
            saveHKRecord(item: currRecord, withSuccess: {
                // success
                //print("record added to array")
            }, failure: {
                // fail
                print("fail to process record")
            })
        }
    }

    func saveHKRecord(item:HKRecord, withSuccess successBlock: @escaping () -> Void, failure failiureBlock: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let unit = HKUnit.init(from: item.unit!)
        let quantity = HKQuantity(unit: unit, doubleValue: item.value)

        var hkSample: HKSample? = nil
        if let type = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier:  HKQuantityTypeIdentifier(rawValue: item.type)) {
            hkSample = HKQuantitySample.init(type: type, quantity: quantity, start: item.startDate, end: item.endDate, metadata: item.metadata)
        } else if let type = HKCategoryType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier(rawValue: item.type)) {
            hkSample = HKCategorySample.init(type: type, value: Int(item.value), start: item.startDate, end: item.endDate, metadata: item.metadata)
        } else if item.type == HKObjectType.workoutType().identifier {
            hkSample = HKWorkout.init(activityType: HKWorkoutActivityType(rawValue: 0)!, start: item.startDate, end: item.endDate, duration: item.value, totalEnergyBurned: HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.init(from: item.totalEnergyBurnedUnit), doubleValue: item.totalEnergyBurned), totalDistance: HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.init(from: item.totalDistanceUnit), doubleValue: item.totalDistance), device: nil, metadata: item.metadata)
        } else {
            print("didnt catch this item - \(item)")
        }

        if let hkSample = hkSample, (self.healthStore?.authorizationStatus(for: hkSample.sampleType) == HKAuthorizationStatus.sharingAuthorized) {
            allHKSampels.append(hkSample)
            successBlock()
        } else {
            failiureBlock()
        }
    }

    func saveAllSamples() {
        saveSamplesToHK(samples: self.allHKSampels, withSuccess: {
            //
        }, failure: {
            //
        })
    }
    func saveSamplesToHK (samples:[HKSample], withSuccess successBlock: @escaping () -> Void, failure failiureBlock: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.healthStore?.save(samples, withCompletion: { (success, error) in
            if (!success) {
                print(String(format: "An error occured saving the sample. The error was: %@.", error.debugDescription))
                failiureBlock()
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.writeCounterLabel?.text = "\(Int((self.writeCounterLabel?.text)!)! + samples.count)"
            }
            successBlock()
        })
    }

    func activityByName(activityName: String) -> HKWorkoutActivityType {
        var res = HKWorkoutActivityType(rawValue: 0)
        switch activityName {
        case "HKWorkoutActivityTypeWalking":
            res = HKWorkoutActivityType.walking
        case "HKWorkoutActivityTypeRunning":
            res = HKWorkoutActivityType.running
        case "HKWorkoutActivityTypeCycling":
            res = HKWorkoutActivityType.cycling
        case "HKWorkoutActivityTypeMixedMetabolicCardioTraining":
            res = HKWorkoutActivityType.mixedMetabolicCardioTraining
        case "HKWorkoutActivityTypeYoga":
            res = HKWorkoutActivityType.yoga
        case "HKWorkoutActivityTypeFunctionalStrengthTraining":
            res = HKWorkoutActivityType.functionalStrengthTraining
        case "HKWorkoutActivityTypeTraditionalStrengthTraining":
            res = HKWorkoutActivityType.traditionalStrengthTraining
        case "HKWorkoutActivityTypeDance":
            res = HKWorkoutActivityType.dance
        default:
            print ("???????")
            print ("Add support for activity - \(activityName)")
            break;
        }
        return res!
    }
}
```

This will handle most of the common HK records and types but not all of them, if you have an export file with missing type you can add them your self in the code.